# Keep state between page reloads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Maybe this is a strange question, but I'm new to Vue and I haven't found an answer.
When I use v-if and v-else everything works fine:

```
<CodeForm v-if="isLoginFormSent" />
<LoginForm v-else />
```

But after I reload the page, everything goes back to the v-if state. Is there a way to make sure that the v-else state is displayed after the page is reloaded?

Comment: Are you saving any of this data into [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or persisting it in any manner?

Comment: @zero298 No. Should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior by Vue or we can say this is how Vue works. On page reload, the state of an application is getting `reset`, and therefore the component will be `re-rendered` based on the initial condition or default data properties.

To persist the data variable on page refresh as well, you'll need to store that somehow by using HTML5 web storage mechanism either in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` or in a `cookie`.

You can set it via `localStorage.setItem()` :

```
localStorage.setItem('isLoginFormSent', JSON.stringify(<value>));
```

And then get it on page load in `created()` or `mounted()` life cycle hook :

```
localStorage.getItem('isLoginFormSent');
```

Answer (score 2):

When the page is reloaded in a Vue app, the state of the components are reset to their initial states and the data properties return to their default values which is why you're experiencing this behavior.

If you want to keep the `v-else` state after a page reload, you can employ a different strategy such as persisting the state in local or session storage, cookies, or URL state such as *Vue Router*.

The easiest way would be to save it in the `localStorage`. Please, go through [this article](https://dev.to/dtinth/simple-localstorage-binding-for-vue-36ip) and learn about how you could levarage `localStorage` to your binding.